# Android Editable CountDownTimer Issue

Tags: java, android, countdown

I'm trying to implement a `CountDownTimer` in the .java of an Android app's activity. This `CountDownTimer` needs to be able to count down from several different pre-set timings that is specified by the user's selection, that which I have solved by using `sharedPreferences()`.

In order to connect the `sharedPreferences` and the `CountDownTimer`'s timing, below are two method's I've tried that do not work:

1) `getInt` from the `sharedPreferences` and then defining an string array and substituting `long milliseconds` (for the `CountDownTimer`) with a `long` value from the array by using `array[int]` and thereafter `valueof()` to that obtained string.

2) By using `{if(sharedPreferences == 123) {int timing = 5000;}}`, but this fails due to the braces that contain the value of `int timing` such that `CountDownTimer` cannot read it as it lies outside of that pair of braces that contain the `if`. Worth mentioning is that it is not possible to move the `CountDownTimer` into the braces.

Quite simply, I'm looking for a solution to an editable `CountDownTimer`. While I'm not asking for a whole tutorial right here on Stackoverflow, it would be nice if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why your approaches don't work because I'm having a problem picturing your code. In general, if you declare `int timing = 0;` inside an if-clause it will only be available within this if-clause. So, to make it available on the outside you also need to declare it there.

I'd start with something like this:

```
int timing = 0;
switch (sharedPreferences) {
    case 123:
        timing = 5000;
    case 124:
        timing = 10000;
    case 125:
        timing = 15000;
    ...
    default:
        timing = 20000;
}
startMyCountdown(timing);
```